# Ef 4 (with linq to Entity query) need shorthand Query to work with one to many(add record)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Suppose i have two tables with one to many relationship (association in EF 4.1) . Now i want to add single new record to a table1(company) with some corresponding related record in table2(services) of that company.
company..1........*..services
In short need shorthand query(Linq to Entity) to work with one to many data storage.
More Specifically

```
       //add company
      company company=new company();// company_id primary key
       company.name="abc";
       company.address=""xyz;
        db.SaveChanges();
       //add related Services with foreign key company_id
```

**Updated:**:: If my Question is ambiguous or something wrong with asked context then do tell me the general(Shorthand) Linq to Entity query to work with adding new record in two tables having one to many relation. same as we used to fetch data like

```
 var data=dbContext.table1.Include("table2");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as "shorthand query" for the data manipulation part. In general **Entity Framework != LINQ to Entities**. Apart from querying there are lot of other services provided by an ORM like Entity Framework.

You can use an approach similar to the below code segment to add new related entities

```
var company = new Company { Name = "Foo", Address = "Bar" };

var serviceA = new Service { Name = "A"};
var serviceB = new Service { Name = "B"};

company.Services = new List<Service> { serviceA, serviceB };

db.Companies.Add(company);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Round brackets on object initializer default constructor are redundant. Meaning, they're completely pointless.

Comment: Erange i used shorthand term with query that means to (Shorthand==Sort) Sorting Linq to Entity Query(to add record in two table with one to many r/t). Like we use Any(), Include()..etc methods  for

Comment: @Kannas Data manipulation is very much dependent on the problem at hand and the entities involved. There would rarely be such reusable methods suited for all data manipulation cases.